# The full story about the decltype + comma trick

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, sfinae, decltype, comma-operator

The title should clarify what my confusion is about. I'd like to use this question to get a comprehensive answer which helps me understand how the comma operator works with `decltype` within SFINAE context. An example usage is shown in [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69350834/c-templates-the-complete-guide-understanding-footnote-comment-about-decltyp).

### A bit of research

Searching for *is:question [c++] [decltype] comma*, one finds [these 6 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+%5Bdecltype%5D+comma):

- (2011) [How is decltype supposed to work with `operator,`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837983/how-is-decltype-supposed-to-work-with-operator) has a promising title, but it is VisualStudio specific and the one and only answer fundamentally claims there's a bug in the compiler indeed.
- (2012) [How is type deduced from auto return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775639/how-is-type-deduced-from-auto-return-type) The accepted answer says the following, with reference to the expression `decltype( ( bool( fun(v[0] ) ), void() ) )`,

  > 1. The expression `bool( fun(v[0] ) )` is not *actually* evaluated, because we're in a *non-evaluated context* (`decltype`, similar to `sizeof`). What matters here is that it *would be* evaluated if the expression as a whole was evaluated, so that if the subexpression is invalid then the whole expression is invalid.
  > 2. `void()` isn't *really* a value, but it behaves like a value in the context of the comma operator and `decltype`.

  which I haven'te really understood.
- (2014) [c++11 decltype returns reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186601/c11-decltype-returns-reference-type) doesn't go into much detail, but the accepted answer expresses the idea that `i, j` is an lvalue expression and, as such, `decltype` returns a reference type for it, so if I correctly understand it essentially says `, 1` can be a tool to disable the special case that `decltype(x)` would be routed to (if `x` is an unparenthesized...), pretty much like `(` and `)` around `x`. Give this, I'd ask whehter `decltype((unparenthesized-name))` and `decltype(unparenthesized-name, 0)` impose the same requirements on *`unparenthesized-name`*.
- (2015) [Why cannot we use brace initializer in an un-evaluated context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688522/why-cannot-we-use-brace-initializer-in-an-un-evaluated-context) together with its in-body question *why cannot we use `void{}` instead?* seems a bit unrelated, as it's mostly about whether one can create a `void` value or not.
- (2015) [SFINAE: `static_cast<void>()` or `, void()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837332/sfinae-static-castvoid-or-void) There's no accepted answer, so if [the asker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/567292/ecatmur) is not happy with any, I trust their rep and badges and I'm not happy with those answers either.
- (2020) [How to use sfinae to exclude types for which a function is defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64896281/how-to-use-sfinae-to-exclude-types-for-which-a-function-is-defined) seems unrelated.

But I haven't understood the full story yet.

### My understanding

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) I read that

> In a comma expression `E1, E2`, the expression `E1` is evaluated, its result is discarded ([…]), and its side effects are completed before evaluation of the expression E2 begins ([…]).
>
> The type, value, and value category of the result of the comma expression are exactly the type, value, and value category of the second operand, `E2`.

so I'm tempted to understand that as far as the code in which `E1, E2` appears is concerned, the only thing that makes the `E1, E2` expression different from just `E2` is the side effects of `E1`.

However the page obviously doesn't adderess the use of `operator,` within `decltype`. So let's see what [`decltype`'s doc page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) has to say:

> The type need not be complete or have an available destructor, and can be abstract. This rule doesn't apply to sub-expressions: in `decltype(f(g()))`, `g()` must have a complete type, but `f()` need not.

(Correct me if I'm wrong, but I guess this sentence applies to the whole point *(2)*, not just point *(2.c)*. Also, I assume that the last `f()` is referring to the *expression* `f(g())`.)

In a comment under [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69350834/c-templates-the-complete-guide-understanding-footnote-comment-about-decltyp), [@cigien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8372853/cigien) comments that passing `f(g())` or `f(), 0` to `decltype` enforces the same requirement of completeness on the return type of `f`.

Based on that, I deduce that `decltype(f(), 0)` is just a way to have something to put in `std::void_t<>` in a SFINAE context when we want to

- make sure `f()` is well formed, ***just as we'd do via `decltype(f())`***,
- but also requiring that the return type be complete, which **wouldn't be** enforced by `decltype(f())`.

The `, 0`, I understand, is just a trick we use to have `f()` be the first argument to `,`. We could just as well do `decltype(f(), f())`, and would enforce the same requirement on `f`; yes, `decltype` would result in the return type of `f` rathern than `int`, but that's irrelevant if we are feeding that type to `std::void_t<>`.

As regards the whole comma trick, however, [HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69352883/5825294) says it is not robust

> So if `begin()` is valid and returns a complete type, but `,` is overloaded and can't be called for some reason, you'll get a false negative

([my demo of the statement above](https://godbolt.org/z/v5shqnfsn)) and proposes `decltype(void(std::declval<T>().begin()))` as a better alternative. But how does *this* work? Why converting to `void` triggers something more than not converting it, i.e. `decltype(std::declval<T>().begin())`?

Comment: "...than not doing it" is this a typo? `decltype(std::declval<T>().begin())` rather than `decltype(void(std::declval<T>().begin()))` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, I'm not sure. I've worded it differently. Is it ok now?

Comment: Comma in `decltype` is used to have several expression to test (`decltype(c.begin(), c.end(), 0)`) and mostly to select the wanted return type. `decltype(f(), 0)` would be `int` whereas `decltype(f(), f())` would be the type returned by `f()`.

Comment: @Jarod42, I know that. _Comma in `decltype` is used to have several expression to test_? Well, I'd than assume that when I see `decltype(x,y)` I could change it to `std::pair<decltype(x), decltype(y)>` (for the purpose of testing `x` and `y`), which doesn't work in general. However, I've clarified why I mentioned `decltype(f(), f())`. Hope that truly clarifies.

Comment: I'm not actually sure what the question is here. Is this just about how `decltype` works? I think the comma doesn't really play into it. Your previous question boils down to `decltype` of a prvalue can yield an incomplete or abstract type, but that doesn't waive those requirements for sub-expressions. `decltype(foo)` -> `decltype(foo, 0)` is one way to make `foo` a sub-expression.

Comment: HolyBlackCat's answer alluded to the fact that this is subject to comma overloading. That is, `foo, 0` being well-formed is not necessarily the same as `foo` being well-formed, because `,` can mean arbitrary things. Casting to `void` doesn't suffer that problem, `decltype(foo)` -> `decltype(void(foo))` only adds a completeness requirement. But this is all just `decltype` rules and already quoted.

Comment: You need to add a paragraph at the beginning to explain what the "trick" is for.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally required that **prvalues** have complete type ([basic.lval]/9), and the exception to that for `decltype` applies only to the expression as a whole ([dcl.type.decltype]/2).  Casting an expression to `void` therefore imposes a completeness requirement on its type (if no reference is involved); the choice of that particular manipulation is driven by its **genericity** (anything can be cast to `void`) and by the **known** resulting type.  This result can be directly matched against a `class=void` template parameter introduced to support such SFINAE, or can have `,` applied (which would also require completeness) without fear of overloading in order to select some other fixed type for the overall expression.